# Find Matching entries in an array in php

Tags: php, array-intersect

So I have two arrays :

```
1. $users_populated = users_populated: Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 10000106
            [username] => 
            [name] => 
            [firstname] => 
            [initial] => 
            [surname] => 
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 10000106
            [username] => 
            [name] =>  
            [firstname] => 
            [initial] => 
            [surname] => 
            [email] => 
            [role] => 
            [roleids] => 
            [platform] => 
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 10000065
            [username] => 
            [name] =>  
            [firstname] => 
            [initial] => 
            [surname] => 
            [email] => 
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 296
            [username] =>
            [name] =>
            [firstname] => 
            [initial] => 
            [surname] => 
            [email] => 
                  )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [id] => 297
            [username] =>
            [name] =>
            [firstname] =>
            [initial] => 
            [surname] =>
            [email] => 
           )
        )

2. $user_list: Array
(
    [0] => 10000106
    [1] => 297
)
```

So I want the values from 1st array which matches the 2nd array 
that is Entries :

```
$output = output: Array
(
[0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 10000106
            [username] => 
            [name] => 
            [firstname] => 
            [initial] => 
            [surname] => 
        )
 [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 297
            [username] =>
            [name] =>
            [firstname] =>
            [initial] => 
            [surname] =>
            [email] => 
           )

)
```

In Short IDs from 1st array and values in 2nd array should match

I have tried using Array intersect key but that didn't work out..

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By looping $users_populated and array_seach function you may obtain the expected result.

```
<?php

$output = array();

// Case 1: This will overlap by using the last appearance of the same ID value if repeated ID appears in $users_populated

foreach($users_populated as $value) {

    if($key = array_search($value['id'], $user_list))

        $output[$key] = $value;

}

// Case 2: This will use the first result found in $users_populated

foreach($users_populated as $value) {

    if(empty($output[$value['id']]) && $key = array_search($value['id'], $user_list))

        $output[$key] = $value;

}

var_dump($output);
```

Hope this is what you want.

Comment: Thanks :) 
This exactly printed what I wanted :)

Answer (score 2):

Use [`array_uintersect()`](https://www.php.net/array_uintersect):

```
$result = array_uintersect($one, $two, function($x, $y)
{
   $x = is_array($x)?$x['id']:$x;
   $y = is_array($y)?$y['id']:$y;
   return $x-$y;
});
```

-your second array is plain, thus it will act directly in callback.

Comment: Thanks...
But I am sorry, I am new to this function.
Can you tell me what I need to add in the $x and $y variables ??

Comment: You don't need to add there anything. It's self-sufficient code, it should work

Comment: When I am using this code in my Netbeans project I am getting a Red highlighted error "Language feature not compatible with PHP version indicated in project settings" .

P.s The code is within a controller named "Groupcontroller.php"

Comment: What is your version? (please, don't tell me it's 5.2 :\ ...)

Comment: when I use it says Fatal error: Unsupported operand types.. (v5.4)

Comment: My bad. PHP will use comparison callback between same-array elements too. Check my edit (fiddle is [here](http://3v4l.org/7u8dn))

Comment: It works fine for me now. I didn't even realize that there are a lots of useful functions XD

Comment: Thanks a ton Alma and Sam for your quick responses :)

Answer (score 0):

When you want to check if two arrays contain the same values, 
regardless of the values' order, you cannot use "==" or "===". 
Try this function .

```
<?php
function array_equal($a, $b) {
    return (is_array($a) && is_array($b) && array_diff($a, $b) === array_diff($b, $a));
}
?>
```